# Easy way to download/upload to S3?

Tags: files-and-directories, external-calls, webservices, serviceexecute, file-transfer

I need to access a bucket to put and get a few files, is there any nice way to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Short of implementing the AWS auth flow / SOAP interface, probably best is to download the Java libraries that AWS provides and run those via JLink.

Comment: A ServiceConnect for aws would be nice

Comment: I've thought about it, but it'll take time to understand the AWS auth-framework and implement the requisite flow. If I used AWS I'd do it, but since I don't I haven't (yet) really felt like doing it.

Comment: use `RunProcess[]` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RunProcess.html with aws-cli?

Comment: Deprecated AWSLink do not work in V12. But for referente: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/168057

Answer (score 1):

Amazon AWS publishes robust SDKs for this purpose.

Try their Boto3 SDK which is in Python: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html

You can execute Python scripts from Mathematica via https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Python.html

To begin, you would pip install boto3 on your local computer and set up the environment. It is explained here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html

For that matter, you could use another language of choice - see their SDK offering for Javahttps://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/ which you could use via Mathematica's J/Link.

Comment: Thanks but this is already known, looking for a real not theoretical answer.

Comment: OK @M.R. perhaps have a look at this post about Wolfram's AWSLink package https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/168057/a-tour-of-awslink/174786#174786