# A tour of AWSLink?

Tags: packages, wolfram-cloud, web-access, webservices, amazon-web-services

Seems like there are a lot of useful functions in this undocumented package `AWSLink`:

[image]

Any developers on here that can demo it a bit?

Comment: They seem to all have usage messages.  Use ``?AWSLink`* `` and keep clicking on the symbol names.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, but a tutorial would be nice!

Comment: That was a hint that if you're interested in the topic, you can start experimenting with guidance from the usage messages. Once you start to get comfortable with the package, you can share a few examples with the rest of us.

Comment: @ericwilliamsmith @murta Would you be able to add a new answer to show how the s3 functionalities in ExternalStorage` work in 12.1?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I haven't used these submarined functions for EC2, but I have found the S3 functionalities in this package to be extremely useful. Since there is currently no documentation in v11.3, I thought at the very least I could share a brief guide to the most important operations.

**Setup AWS CLI**

`AWSLink` uses the AWS command line tool under the hood, so you need install the [cli and configure it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html). Just follow the linked tutorial, which helps you set up your `~/.aws/credentials` file and aws-mfs to authenticate (if you use multi-factor auth).

Once you are able to use `aws` on the command line like this:

```
aws s3 ls s3://your_bucket/path_to_your_data  # to list bucket contents
```

you will be good to go.

**Package Features**

There are three main classes of functions in the package: general functionality (symbols like `AWS*`), operators for Elastic Compute Cloud (`EC2*`), and those relating to Simple Storage Service (`S3*`).

[image]

**Connecting**

To get started, use `AWSClientConnect` to create a connection object for one of the two supported services you want to use (***lowercase*** "ec2" or "s3"):

[image]

**Create buckets**

Given the client object, you can create a bucket:

```
S3CreateBucket[c, "datascience"]
```

**List all buckets**

You can list all top-level buckets:

```
S3DescribeBuckets[c]
```

[image]

**Inspect buckets**

Say you have a specific top-level bucket named `s3://datascience`, you can retrieve a nested `Association` describing its contents

```
ds = S3Bucket[c, "datascience"]
S3DescribeBucketContent @ ds
```

[image]

or get a summary of bucket properties `{"CreationDate", "BucketName", "Owner", "Region"}` with `Dataset[ds]`.

**Access sub-directories**

Some important `AWSLink` symbols return inert objects that meant to be used as arguments to other functions that page through or act on them lazily. One such function is `AWSCollectionReadList`, which we use to inspect folders within a bucket.

For example, to see the files inside `s3://datascience/features/example1/`

```
objs = AWSCollectionReadList[
  S3BucketObjects[ds, Prefix -> "features/example1/"]]
```

[image]

which returns a list of `S3Objects`. In this example, there were four files in that folder. If I didn't use the `StartAfter` option we would have gotten five things in the list. `AWSCollectionReadList` always returns the bucket folder (which is really just a key itself) as the first `S3Object` in the list.

**Download from a bucket**

After using `AWSCollectionReadList` you get a list of `S3Object`'s. To pull those objects down use `S3DownloadAsynchronous`, which works like so:

[image]

For example,

```
S3DownloadAsynchronous[{objs[[1]] -> File["~/local/path/to/downloaded.tsv.gz"]}]
```

**Uploate to a bucket**

To upload a single file to a top-level bucket use `S3UploadAsynchronous`, this returns an `S3TaskObject`:

[image]

**Upload to a specific folder**

To upload files to various paths in a specific bucket use `S3UploadAsynchronous`.  For example, you can upload a single file

```
S3UploadAsynchronous[ds, {File["~/local/path/to/your_file.tsv.gz"]} -> 
{"features/example2/your_file.tsv.gz.h5"}]
```

or upload a folder of thousands of images:

```
fns = FileNames["*.jpg", "~/images_to_upload"]
uploads =  File /@ fns -> (("features/example2/" <> FileNameTake[#, -1]) & /@ fns)
Dynamic[AsynchronousTasks[], UpdateInterval -> 3] (* to monitor progress *)
st = S3UploadAsynchronous[ds, uploads]
```

Note that conveniently, any intermediate directories that don't currently exist will be created for you, but you need to list out each file explicitly, it doesn't do recursive upload on a directory (like `cp -R`).

Ok, hope this is useful to someone!

Comment: Thank you this is amazing!

Comment: If the are any other things you’d like to see explained just add a comment

Comment: @M.R. How to pass `--profile ` in the `AWSClientConnect`? I have configured the AWS CLI for different profiles (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-multiple-profiles.html). For example this `aws s3 ls --profile test` works on my terminal and lists the buckets.

Comment: Heads up for version 12. S3 functions have been moved to `ExternalStorage\`` , which is another unpublished library. There are new function names too so older code will need to be updated. Source: Wolfram support

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith Thanks for the note, btw, can you answer Platomaniac's question above?

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith, It's still working in 12.1? I can't find how to configure S3 with `ExternalStorage`.

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith I was hoping then if this important functionality is deprecated or changed, that you would kindly please add a new updated answer?

Comment: @M.R. I use REST APIs with S3, so I'm not using the built in packages. 12.1 no longer requires the hidden packages either. I haven't used them so I can't really update the answer at this point.

Comment: @EricWilliamSmith if you could share your Rest API code it would be nice.!