# How to interact with Amazon S3 using Mathematica?

Tags: packages, amazon-web-services

Unfortunately Mathematica 12.1 does not have a native way of handling S3 files, the S3 functions were removed from the experimental AWSLink package.

Someone know where can I download it, or some other package to handle S3 in Mathematica?

[Here is a post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174786/2266) with more information about the package.

[Crosspost](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1932000) in Wolfram Community

Comment: FindFile["AWSLink`"] works for me on 12.1 on Windows and Linux.
"C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram \
Research\\Mathematica\\12.1\\SystemFiles\\Links\\AWSLink\\Kernel\\init.m" and "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/SystemFiles/Links/AWSLink/Kernel/init.m"

Comment: @RolfMertig nice to see your here. Yes the package is there, but if you execute ?AWSLink`*, you will check that in 12.1 the S3 function were removed. Now the package has just the EC2 functions.